# how does mysql auto increment knows which id to continue from after rows are deleted?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

if i inserted rows and deleted them the A_I will know from what key to continue [somthing with UNIQUE i know] but i'm interested of knowing about the proccess and where does the mysql store the values. just for my private knowledge

cheers.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL maintains the current value internally.

Once a value is used, it is never used again.  This even includes values used within rolled back transactions, failed inserts, deleted records, etc.

Effectively, if MySQL ever even *attempts* to use an id, the counter increments and MySQL will never use those old values again.  This *naivity* makes the system of allocating unique values simpler and so both faster and more reliable.

Well, nearly.  You *can* over-ride this and force MySQL to recommence it's auto incrementing values from any number of your choice.  But that is *generally* neither necessary nor recommended.

Answer (score 2):

If a table is set to use Auto Increment, it stores the current index in a seperate variable which is incremented every time something is inserted.

Comment: yeah but where can i see it? that seperate variable , how the system stores it?

Comment: I think it is stored in the table's file as a seperate value. I guess it equals a 64-Bit long integer, but I relly never cared that much about how its stored than what it is good for

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the stored variable using the [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.